# MySQL, import SQL dump with another database

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, import, migration

I have an SQL dump of db1 that contains this line:

"USE db1"

If I import that file into db2 with:

```
mysql -D db2 -uroot -p < /var/backups/db1.sql.gz
```

Is there the risk that db1 will be overriden?

Comment: Can manual rewriting the database name be an option?

Comment: Unfortunately that SQL dump is very big and I have no possibilities to modify it.

Comment: Which operating system are you running on? If it's a unix variant, then a tool like sed should have no problems replacing all`USE db1` statements with `USE db2` ones (might take a while, but it'll do it).

Comment: Even on Windows you can use a grep replacement for updating that file. See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tool-for-windows).

Comment: @Marian [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

Comment: @dezso: Thanks, it was mentioned in that SO question. I started to play with it and Agent Ransack (another tool featured there) :-). They should be able to handle big files easily.

Answer (score 4):

By reading the official documentation, I'll say that your guess is right, the dump script will override the DB1 database.

[MySQL Use db syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html)

> The USE db_name statement tells MySQL to use the db_name database as the default (current) database for subsequent statements. The database remains the default until the end of the session or another USE statement is issued.

The solution is the one proposed by Stuart, use a grep-like tool to find and replace "use db1" with "use db2" inside the dump file. Maybe even other references to db1 inside the dump script (procedures that use complete table names..). There are solutions for both Linux or Windows variants to edit that big text file.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from using `sed` to remove the `USE db1` statement, if you can take a new dump of the database:

```
mysqldump db1 > newdump.sql
```

should generate the dump without the `USE db1` statement.